# How to deploy TFS aggregator in TFS 2018

Tags: tfs, tfs-aggregator

I'm not sure that [TFS-aggregator](https://tfsaggregator.github.io/) will work in `Tfs2018.Update1.RC1`

But as per the below image, it should work(I hope)

[image]

I'm trying to do some POC by creating a rule using TFS aggregator

All works fine when I tested my rules using `TFSAggregator2.ConsoleApp.exe`

Now I want to deploy this rule to my original TFS *(which will automatically trigger for every save on the WIT)*

I've followed the instruction from [here](https://tfsaggregator.github.io/admin/install/#manual-setup)

As per that the Step 5 is,

> 5. Copy `TFSAggregator2.ServerPlugin.dll`, `TFSAggregator2.Core.dll` and
>      `TFSAggregator2.ServerPlugin.policies` to the plugin location on the
>      Application Tier of your TFS Servers:
>
> The plugin folder is usually at this path for TFS 2017: `C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 15.0\Application Tier\Web
>   Services\bin\Plugins`; You must copy the exact same files on all TFS
>   Application Tier servers. TFS detects automatically that a file was
>   copied in and will load it in.
>
> You can verify if assembly version matches TFS version using this
>   Powershell code

### My Problem

I couldn't able to find the `TFSAggregator2.ServerPlugin.dll`, `TFSAggregator2.Core.dll` in my current directory which looks like this

[image]

The two `dlls` were already in the destination folder!

[image]

So I just copy and paste my `TFSAggregator2.ServerPlugin.policies` from `C:\Program Files\TFS Aggregator\samples` to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2018\Application Tier\Web Services\bin\Plugins`

**I thought this will work but it's not working**

***Solutions so far which I tried***

Restarted the tfsjobagent `net stop tfsjobagent` , `net start tfsjobagent`

Comment: `RC1`? Update 3 is out... In theory it should work, but I'm not entirely sure. The installer will detect the right server version, if supported, and drop the files, so it looks like it should work.

Comment: Have you checked the debugging tips in the aggregator docs? Did you set the correct permissions for the tfs service user?

Comment: https://tfsaggregator.github.io/admin/troubleshooting/

Comment: @jessehouwing Thanks.. waiting for your response! yes as per the troubleshooting guide. I've added the local service account to my project collection administrator. Still not working

Comment: Just copy and pasting the `TFSAggregator2.ServerPlugin.policies` to the pluging location is enough to deployment ?

Comment: That should do it.

Comment: @jessehouwing I couldn't able to find any event logs (Event viewer) related to TFSAggregator! which makes me difficult to find the root cause. Do you have any idea to troubleshoot it ?

Comment: Did you tweak the logging? https://tfsaggregator.github.io/admin/logging/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179367/discussion-between-jessehouwing-and-jayendran).